# Rename dendrogram leaves using table of codes

Tags: python, tree

In a .ph tree:

```
GCF_900039355.1:3.966592789,(((GCF_001372255.1:4.133090019,GCF_000321125.2:3.866909981):0.07335448265,GCF_000590075.1:3.931073904):0.02735507488,GCF_001186415.1:3.951286316):0.009964346886
```

And a code table where the names of leaves have real names:

```
GCF_900039355.1 A
GCF_001372255.1 B
GCF_000321125.2 C
GCF_000590075.1 D
GCF_001186415.1 E
```

The solution was to use the same name and it subscribed the previous tree file:

```
    d = {"GCF_900039355.1":"A", "GCF_001372255.1":"B", "GCF_000321125.2":"C", "GCF_000590075.1":"D", "GCF_001186415.1":"E"}

    tree = "GCF_900039355.1:3.966592789,(((GCF_001372255.1:4.133090019,GCF_000321125.2:3.866909981):0.07335448265,GCF_000590075.1:3.931073904):0.02735507488,GCF_001186415.1:3.951286316):0.009964346886"

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    tree = string.replace(tree, k, v)
print tree
```

Comment: Don't post the solution into the question, post it *as answer!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was this, substitute all strings at the same time renaming the previous text.

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    tree = string.replace(tree, k, v)
print tree
```